# Need help implementing choose statement in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

For a school project I had to generate a XML file with random entities and create an xslt for it. The idea is that every person has 0 or more bank accounts and every bank account has 1 bank card for it.

Now I want to integrate a choose statement in my code.

```
  <!-- Keys -->
  <xsl:key match="bankaccount" use="account_id" name="keytobankaccount"/>
  <xsl:key match="bankcard" use="card_id" name="keytocard"/>


  <!-- Bank Account -->
  <xsl:for-each select="key('keytobankaccount', id)">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <p> IBAN: <xsl:value-of select="iban"/> </p>
    <p> Account balance: <xsl:value-of select="balance"/> </p>

     <!-- Bank card -->
     <xsl:for-each select="key('keytocard', bank_id)">
      <p> Card Nr.: <xsl:value-of select="card_nr"/> </p>
      <p> Card: <xsl:value-of select="card_type"/> </p>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </li>
  </ul>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Inside **<xsl:for-each select="key('keytobankaccount', id)">**:
If **keytobankaccount** has the same value as the attribute **id**, output:

```
  <ul>
   <li>
    <p> IBAN: <xsl:value-of select="iban"/> </p>
    <p> Account balance: <xsl:value-of select="balance"/> </p>
     <xsl:for-each select="key('keytocard', bank_id)">
      <p> Card Nr.: <xsl:value-of select="card_nr"/> </p>
      <p> Card: <xsl:value-of select="card_type"/> </p>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </li>
  </ul>
```

Else:

```
<p>No account found!</p>
```

How can I implement that choose statement?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] including input and expected output.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I edited the code and my in-/output. Hope it's ok like that.